# Prevent hovering effect after pointer moves away

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to display an element on hover. Following code does it. However there is a problem, if you hover over multiple times, the element keeps displaying as many times when the cursor goes away.

Hover over the link multiple times in the demo to understand the problem.

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.box').delay(100).fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.box').delay(100).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
  <li>
    Show
    <div class="box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu condimentum odio, non congue quam. Cras feugiat nulla at mattis semper.
    </div>
  </li>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/e99afrg8/

Comment: jQuery animations are queued. jQuery's [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) might be helpful.

Comment: Hows that for assistance, 6 answers in 8 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery animations are queued by default. So, as you hover on and off rapidly, all those animations are queued up and continue playing after you stop hovering.

I suggest using [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) to "[s]top the currently-running animation on the matched elements."

In my example, I have also chosen to clear the queue but *not* jump to the end of the current animation. You may want to experiment with those values and see which behavior you prefer.

> .stop( [clearQueue ] [, jumpToEnd ] )

```js
$('li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.box').stop(true,false).delay(100).fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.box').stop(true,false).delay(100).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #FFF;
  width: 200px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="images">
  <li>
    Show
    <div class="box">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu condimentum odio, non congue quam. Cras feugiat nulla at mattis semper.
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Nothing wrong with jQuery, but you can go lighter with CSS `:hover` and `transition`.

No more post-hovering display effect.

```css
.box {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    /* display: none; */
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div:hover .box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: all .1s linear .1s; /* property, duration, timing-function, delay */
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <li>
        Show
        <div class="box">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
            Fusce eu condimentum odio, non congue quam. 
            Cras feugiat nulla at mattis semper.
        </div>
    </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To show the `.box` element on mouse hover "Show" word, you only need to add a CSS rule.

See this example without javascript.

```css
.box {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 200px;
    background: #000;
     position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

li:hover .box {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <li>
        Show
        <div class="box">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu condimentum odio, non congue quam. Cras feugiat nulla at mattis semper.
        </div>    
        </li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With jquery:

```
 $(".show").hover(
    function () {
        $(".box").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
    },
    function () {
        $(".box").stop(true, true).fadeOut(500);
    }
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just using css to do that

```css
.box {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 200px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

li:hover .box{
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `li` is a block element. So when you move the mouse over *any* part of the `li` the hover takes effect. If you only want the box to appear when the text is hovered over, you can adjust...

Add a `<span>` wrapping the text....

```
<div id="images">
    <li>
       <span>Show</span>
        <div class="box">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce eu condimentum odio, non congue quam. Cras feugiat nulla at mattis semper.
        </div>    
        </li>
</div>
```

Then hover over the `span` rather than the `li` itself:

```
$('li span').hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.box').delay(100).fadeIn(); 
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().find('.box').delay(100).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/e99afrg8/1/)**

And you *do* realize that `div` tag containing an `li` is invalid HTML right? Only `ul` tags should contain `li` tags.